# CakePHP: Retrieving hasAndBelongsToMany data for a user

Tags: cakephp, many-to-many, cakephp-1.3

I want to return data which belongs to only 1 user in a hasAndBelongsToMany relationship. I'm not sure about the conditions here:
I'm getting warning:

`Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054:  Unknown column 'UsersFood.user_id' in 'where clause'`

Can someone clarify with this?

```
return $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
                'Food.id' => 'Usersfood.food_id',
                'Usersfood.user_id' => $userid,
                 'User.id' => $userid

                )

     )

   );
```

Comment: Notice the capitalisation in this snippet from the manual:('RecipesTag.tag_id'=>124) Remember, PHP is case-sensitive.

Comment: Notice also the alpha order ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been found. I literally read through Containable and Join and decided to go with Join.

> A). http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables
>
> Also thanks to this comment:
>
> B). http://book.cakephp.org/comments/index/1325

Answer (score 0):

```
return $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array(
                 'User.id' => $userid
                )
     )

   );
```

If you have `$hasAndBelongsToMany` set, you won't need to specify `'Food.id' => 'Usersfood.food_id',` and `'Usersfood.user_id' => $userid,`
`

Comment: surprisingly I'm getting the same error: `Unknown column 'UsersFood.user_id' in 'where clause` I've changed according to yours

Comment: have you set the `hasAndBelongsToMany`?

Comment: Yes I have set the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have defined the relation properly as per this page http://book.cakephp.org/view/83/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

Then look at http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable

specific user with that users food.

`$this->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 123), 'contain' => array('Food')));`

or all with food per user

`$this->find('all', array('contain' => array('Food')));`

Comment: I'm not getting any far with your answer, but thanks. If possible, I hope maybe you could write the correct one? The containable part is one which has few examples. None really apply to my work here. Should I be using join instead?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be **FoodsUser** rather than **UsersFood**?

Assuming you're following convention, this is from the book: "This new join table's name needs to include the *names of both models involved, in alphabetical order*, and separated with an underscore ( _ )."

Now the underscore is for the *database* table name. Following the convention, the model name will be **FoodsUser**

Comment: To answer your question, no, when we bake tables which have HABTM relationships, we only get to name our main tables, but not the bridge tables. Did you know about aroc_acos ? isn't it non-alphabetical order?

Comment: I don't know which manual you are reading, but the official one is quite explicit on the alphabetical naming convention. Unless you are experienced or have a specific business need to do otherwise, I recommend that you follow that convention. I have used HABTM and ACL extensively. aroc_acos (sic) is only reverse-alpha if you type it that way. In my applications it is acos_aros & AcosAro

Comment: What are you talking Leo ?? I said when you bake (..) Can you please read the comment above again ? and same goes to ACL example if we run the shell. If you're doing manually then we're doing things differently. That's all.

Comment: Okay, now I'm home I've just created the tables alphas, alphas_zetas and zetas. I 'baked' the models and was asked along the way what I wanted to call everything and which tables I wanted to use. The aliases were Alpha, AlphasZeta and Zeta. The whole thing worked perfectly. As I described. As the book describes.

Comment: Leo, I'm sorry but are you doing it differently? when you create 2 tables with HABTM relationship, you don't have to create the join table by yourself, I wonder why you do it that way. Anyway the question has been solved. To try to answer your doubt; ok, you have alphas and zetas. Each corresponds to each other with a HABTM. So as you bake, you bake alphas and zetas each separately. You won't need to bake the join/bridge table, in your case, you named is as "alphas_zetas". I hope I clear your doubt why my table is named that way, also I don't find it a big problem with non-alphabetical order.